# Netbeans lack of SVN Add

Tags: svn, netbeans, continuous-integration, netbeans-6.9

I've been driving myself crazy over the past few days over this one.  We've just finished setting up a Hudson Continuous-Integration server.  So it runs a build script each and every commit to validate the commit.  The issue is that it validates that all the files in the repo have both the `svn:keywords = "Id"` and `svn:eol-style = "LF"` properties set on all `.php` files, which normally would be great (The last time I did this, I used Eclipse and Tortoise SVN, which both have svn::add functionality).

But the problem is that I've grown quite accustomed to Netbeans.  And Netbeans has no `svn add` function that I can find (It add files automatically upon commit).  The problem is that I can't add the properties until the files are added.  If I commit without adding the properties, the build will fail.  So I wind up failing the build every other commit because I need to take 5 steps (commit, recursive propset, commit, acknowledge failed build, delete failed build),  to do something that would normally only take 2 (propset, commit).

I don't really want to go back to Eclipse at this point, but when it takes me 20 minutes to commit because I need to do everything 4 times, it's going to get old quickly...  Is there some workaround that I'm missing (Short of removing the property check, which will defeat the point, since I want those properties set anyway)?  Or am I just SOL?...

Comment: Does Netbeans respect the ~/.subversion/config file? If so, you can tell svn to automatically set those properties by changing the `[auto-props]` section to include `*.php = svn:eol-style=LF;svn:keywords=Id`

Comment: @Kaleb Pederson:  Make that an answer please.  I never even realized it had that file (I have it set in my `subversion` config file, but I just looked and it turns out NetBeans has it's own copy)...  That may have done it (I'm going to check now)...

Comment: Didn't work.  Netbeans overwrites the file periodically.  So it never gets used...  I'll dig deeper tomorrow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion has a `~/.subversion/config` file that allows you to customize a number of different settings, among which is *auto-props*, properties that are automatically set on files based on their extension:

So, assuming Netbeans respects that file, you can tell svn to automatically set those properties by changing the `[auto-props]` section to include `*.php = svn:eol-style=LF;svn:keywords=Id`

For example:

```
[auto-props]
# here's yours
*.php = svn:eol-style=LF;svn:keywords=Id
# and one with multiple keywords
*.c = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Rev Id HeadURL
# and one with a mime-type
*.png = svn:mime-type=image/png
```

**UPDATE**:

Netbeans 6.9 appears to read in the `~/.subversion/config` file on *startup* and does NOT pickup changes without a restart. After restarting Netbeans, it correctly picks up my selected *auto-props* and applies them to each newly created file.

**UPDATE 2**:

Netbeans appears to read through both the global and personal subversion configuration files (among many other subversion files) when it starts up. Here's a relevant portion as seen by strace:

```
stat("/home/kibab/.subversion/config", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4576, ...}) = 0
open("/home/kibab/.subversion/config", O_RDONLY) = 28
open("/etc/subversion/config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/kibab/.netbeans/6.9/config/svn/config/config", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=825, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/kibab/.netbeans/6.9/config/svn/config", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=61, ...}) = 0
open("/home/kibab/.netbeans/6.9/config/svn/config/config", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 28
```

Further examination seems to imply that once it's read through the config files, it then writes out a copy (using `O_TRUNC`) of the configuration file which it stores at `~/.netbeans/6.9/config/svn/config/config` (at least on Linux).

Based on this, I assume that Netbeans is attempting to be intelligent enough to use whatever subversion settings you have set in your config files, both global and personal.

Comment: Well, I commented above, but it appears as if Netbeans is reloading that file every time I perform any kind of SVN activity (commit, update, etc).  I can't find a setting for it inside of netbeans...  I'll just have to dig more tomorrow...

Comment: I tested on my copy of Netbeans-6.9. I couldn't find a place to specify the `auto-props` within the IDE, but it does respect changes to `~/.subversion/config` after a restart of Netbeans.

Comment: I tried that.  My version has it in both `~/.subversion/config` and in `~/.netbeans/6.9/config/Subversion/config`.  The second one is the one that keeps getting overwritten.  (This is on Windows btw)...  I'll play around with it more tomorrow when I'm at work...

Comment: That did it.  All I needed to do was edit the correct config file.  The file that did it was `~\Application Data\Subversion\config`.  All others were being ignored.  Thanks for the help!